# WordPress Website Minify Javascript & CSS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance

I'm hope you can shed some more insight on this topic for me. The website I'm currently working on has a terrible page speed test grade. One of the failing grades is the external JavaScript files. Which is telling me to combine these files in order to resolve this issue. I'm hesitating on moving forward with this because the JS files are associated with plugins. Please provide some feedback on what you think would be the best approach. Thank you.

1. Regardless which plugin it is combine all JS files into one and store it on the root directory.
2. Only combine JS files that are related too each of the specified plugins
3. Use a WordPress Minify plugin to get the job done.

Option one I'm nervous that once it comes time to update the plugin it may break. Can't have this happen due to heavy slider animation for galleries, can't afford the downtime.

Option two seems to be the most logical approach. However, what impact will this have when updating the plugin

Option three seems too good to be true. If it is though, please share some of the plugins that you've had success using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true, the reason WP can be sluggish is because it's so easy to bloat it with third-party plugins. From my experience, you can only fiddle around with other people's code so much before it's easier to write your own - especially in an ecosystem that gets updated as often as WP's.

**I wouldn't recommend trying to combine files manually** unless you know what every bit of code in each of the installed plugins does and how the files are included in the background. Also, all your work will be overwritten on the next plugin update.

**Ideally**, what I would do is look for the plugins which cause the most code bloat (*you know, those plugins that come with all the nice addons and integrations and skins and layouts and features, but which you only really use to display a single widget on your contact page - we all have one*) and roll my own lightweight solution so I can remove the plugins altogether.

If you can't do that due to lack of time/money/patience/interest, your best bet is to use a minifier or "scripts to footer" plugin to *at least* move the slow stuff down the rendering line.

And don't forget: in the end, don't aim to get a higher score on a pagespeed test (like google's), aim to get a load time that is reasonable for your content and your users.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Cloudflare service (it has a free plan). It contains an "Auto Minify" feature, where you can choose to minify:

- CSS
- Javascript
- HTML

That way, you don't need to deal with the various plugins and you can quickly turn the minification off if it creates any problems.

Cloudflare also has other features that can improve page speed test, so give it a try.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I did consider this as an option but it's not as fail safe as I would like it to be. What really sold the deal is when they were hacked. https://blog.cloudflare.com/the-four-critical-security-flaws-that-resulte/